# Set function which is measure but not monotone

Tags: measure-theory

I know if $u$ is set function on algebra $A$ then $u$ is a measure iff $u$ is finitely additive and countably subadditive. But will the statement hold if $A$ is any collection of subsets of a set $X$?

I feel certainly not since proving the above fact for algebra we are using properties like if two sets are in $A$ then their difference is also in $A$ and clearly this won't hold for any collection.

So I basically want a counter example for this: If $u$ is set function on $C$ ( any collection of subsets of $X$) which is a measure but $u$ is not monotone and countably subadditive. Any hints?

Comment: Given a set $X$, there is only one collection of all subsets of $X$: the _power set_ of $X$.  It is uniquely determined, so the qualifier "any" does not apply.  The power set of $X$ is automatically a $\sigma$-algebra.  Why wouldn't it be closed under set differences?

If you are looking for a positive measure that is not monotone, there aren't any: every positive measure is monotone -- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measure_is_Monotone.  (An elegant and clear exposition can be found in B. Z. Vulikh's "Brief course on the theory of functions").

Comment: But I am not saying A is collection of 'all' subsets of X, rather A is any collection of some subsets of X.

Comment: @avs Sorry I mistakenly written "all" inside  parentheses at the end.I just realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\{\emptyset , \{1\}, \{1,2\}\}$ in $\mathbb R$. Let $\mu (\emptyset)=0, \mu \{1\}=1,\mu (\{1,2\})=0$. Then $\mu $ is countably additive but not monotone.